# How to get value from a async function and update in UI on any change?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am fairly new in Flutter. I am working on a project and using HIVE for local storage and Provider for state management. I made a cart section where i am string all the dishes added in cart in Local storage and i want to show total amount of the cart in that screen. This is my HIVE object:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class DishHive extends HiveObject {

 DishHive({
required this.dishId,
required this.dishName,
required this.dishDescription,
required this.dishImage,
required this.dishPrice,
this.quantity,
});

@HiveField(0)
String dishId;

@HiveField(1)
String dishName;

@HiveField(2)
String dishDescription;

@HiveField(3)
List<int> dishImage;

@HiveField(4)
int dishPrice;

@HiveField(5)
int? quantity;}
```

I also have made a provider class of functions that will help me in CRUD operations with HIVE along with a function to give me total of cart.

```
class CartFunctions extends ChangeNotifier {
 int Total = 0;
 List<DishHive> cartItems = [];

void setTotal(int total) {
Total = total;
}

void onChange() {
notifyListeners();
}
getCartTotal() async {
List<DishHive> listDish = [];
int TotalofCart = 0;
final box = await Hive.openBox<DishHive>('toCart');

listDish = box.values.toList();

listDish.forEach((element) {
  TotalofCart = TotalofCart + (element.dishPrice * element.quantity!);
});
print('Total: $TotalofCart');
setTotal(TotalofCart);
//notifyListeners();
return Total;
}
```

and below is where I want to fetch total.

```
trailing: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                      future: cartObj.getCartTotal(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snap) {
                        if (snap.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.active) {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: const Color(0xFF265cff),
                          );
                        } else if (snap.hasData) {
                          print('Final Total: ${snap.data}');
                          return Text(snap.data.toString());
                        }
                        return Text('0');
                      },
                    ),
```

The problem i am facing is the value of total in declared in 2nd code snippet always remain 0. It only give me total inside **getCartTotal** function but that is only getting updated in UI once i refresh or switch pages back and forth. I want real time update.
I amd also new to Stack Overflow, if i'm wrong somewhere please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you're continuously calling `cartObj.getCartTotal()` as the tree is rebuilt which is resetting your total AND the future for the future builder is never resolved. You want to store that future in state and monitor the future instead of calling it directly in your build method.

```dart
class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  /// state variable for storing the future
  Future<int>? cartTotal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// store the future in state
    cartTotal = cartObj.getCartTotal();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      /// use the stored future with the future builder...
      future: cartTotal,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snap) {
        if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: const Color(0xFF265cff),
          );
        } else if (snap.hasData) {
          print('Final Total: ${snap.data}');
          return Text(snap.data.toString());
        }
        return Text('0');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had done according to this but still it is happening. It is not updating value in UI. If you don't find can i send you a link of entire file that is working on this part? Can you have a look?

Comment: You can post it in a gist and I'll take a look.

Comment: 1. https://gist.github.com/sumitt194/ed239b0a17dc87fde491fbb4957f883a   |  2. https://gist.github.com/sumitt194/4bf2d6fe8b6483bcdf97c87030d17711    |  3. https://gist.github.com/sumitt194/abec6e0f8f84e076f51192d2927e9809    |   4. https://gist.github.com/sumitt194/f8e634e7de0dbeb8e0754683e3f1f3f2    |  I tried adding numberings and proper description in each gist, so that you can understand which file is doing what. Please go through them.